# htacess subdomain to domain folder invisible with Slim Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, slim

I come here to ask you on the **best practice** for this situation. I red some others questions on Slim / rewrite / htaccess, but no success. No problem encountered here, I just don't know if it's a good practice.

So, with Slim Framework 3, I have a main domain **www.domain.com**, and a subdomain **api.domain.com**.

When I put in address bar **api.domain.com/messages**, it call **www.domain.com/api/messages** with transparency, no redirection.

To achieve this trick, I put this in my index.php file :

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'api.domain.com') {
  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/api' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

It works very well and I don't want to spend time with rewriting rules... But if anybody have a suggestion, I appreciate it !

Thank you for reading !

Comment: Why do you want to use a subdomain if your application alreay interpret the /api endpoint ?

Comment: Hi ! I want to plug apps, games results, arduino & open data to this api in the future, and I have a website on the **www.domain.com**. I prefer have an address like **api.domain.com/game/space-invaders** rather than **www.domain.com/api/game/space-invaders**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it is to create an api directory in your root directory with an index.php file to handle your api requests.  So in your public/index.php file you could add:

```
// public/index.php
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// api domain so include the api routes
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "api.domain.com") {
    require 'api/index.php';
    exit;
}

// --------------------------------------------
// non api domain

$app = new Slim\App;

$app->get('/',function($request,$response) {
    return $response->write("I'm not the API site!");
});

$app->run();
```

And then handle your api routes separately in the api/index.php file:

```
// api/index.php
$app = new Slim\App;

$app->get('/',function($request,$response) {
    return $response->withJson('base api');
});

$app->group('/game',function() {

    $this->get('',function($request,$response) {
        return $response->withJson('Select a game');
    });

    $this->get('/space-invaders',function($request,$response) {
        return $response->withJson('Space Invaders API');
    });

    $this->get('/pacman',function($request,$response) {
        return $response->withJson('Pac Man API');
    });
});

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there it is ! For my case, I made a folder for each subdomain, one for my website and a public :

- public
- src

  - api
  - game
  - app
  - admin
  - www
- vendor

All subdomains point to my **index.php** in the **public** folder. Then **index.php** switch with **http_host** the good app file in the asked folder ( like src/api/app.php ).

In each subfolders ( api, admin, ... ), same structure with an app file, database schema, views or not, ressources, ...

Like this, all the parts have separated filesystem, but they share the same database and vendors. I prevent that I need this structure for a specific need. I don't want to install a Slim for each part...

Thank you for your help !